# Create a Class for using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I wanted to know if it is necessary to use "Using {var ..}" and if it is necessary to use "Dispose ()" and how to use it. And also want to know if this class is correct.

```
class DbConect
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    public string DbName { get; set; }

    public DbConect(string dbName)
    {
        DbName = dbName;
        conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={DbName};");
        conn.Open();
    }


    public DataTable ExecuteSql(String comm)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comm))
        {
            return null;
        }

        SQLiteCommand comando = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
        comando.CommandText = comm;

        SQLiteDataReader rquery = comando.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable resp = new DataTable();
        resp.Load(rquery);

        rquery.Close();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to open the connection in your constructor?

Comment: In general, anything that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) should be either disposed of in a `finally` block or wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: Answers go in answer-boxes, not in the question itself. Please let the question stand as-is, so as to not invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

axlj's answer covers the specific points in your question.
For a slightly different angle, it would be very difficult to create an easier, better-implemented class for use with SQLite than [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). As a side benefit, Dapper supports stronger database systems such as SQL Server and PostgreSQL, should you ever choose to move in that direction, though the SQL itself usually needs to be rewritten.
You might start with an [SQLite/Dapper tutorial](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/sqlite-simple-database-with-dapper/).

Comment: @jonathancunha: Database, joins, SQL, object binding -- It can be a little overwhelming. StackOverflow is here to help you with your questions, provided you do the work to formulate good questions.
As for Dapper, I think you will find it makes database use easier to learn, not harder. You have to use data from SQLite in your program eventually, and Dapper handles the leg work for you. StackOverflow itself uses Dapper, but with Microsoft SQL Server rather than SQLite.